# Execute JS script if screen is certain size

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a menu bar on the side of my webpage that when a screen is a certain size it opens the menu up from the right by a certain amount.

- If the screen is greater than 600 but less that 992, then it opens
  250px.
- If the screen is less that 600, then it opens at 100%.

So far I can get the JS to work by itself - but then I try to use 'if($(window).width() >= 600) {}' then none of it works (I have a button to open - but it loses its functionality with the below code.

Below is my initial working;

```
if($(window).width() >= 600) {
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  }
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}

if($(window).width() < 600) {
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  }
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

---

I know that individually these work - but will work with all screen sizes.

```
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  }
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
```

Comment: You'd be much better off doing this using CSS media queries than in javascript, but if you _need_ js I'd suggest putting the conditional inside the functions instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should declare the function outside the if block and can call them inside the if block. Right now you're declaring the function inside the if that could possibly the reason of code not working

Comment: Thanks - this helped. managed to get it sorted with the below;

'function openNavi() {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    openNavFull();
  } else {
    openNav();
  }
}
function closeNavi() {
    closeNav();
}'

Comment: I'm glad that this helped you. Happy coding